# How to protect exposed bathroom fan wiring

Tags: wiring, bathroom, exhaust-fan

I‘m replacing a builder’s bathroom vent fan and housing. I have two problems.

1. The new housing’s knockout cover is missing. Manufacturer doesn’t have a replacement.
2. The (rigid metallic) conduit leaves wiring exposed.

How can I wire this without leaving anything exposed? I have no attic access.

[image: Ceiling wiring]
[image: Open knockout & fan wires]

Comment: Can you return the fan to where you bought it from and get a replacement?

Comment: No. I bought it with a gift card so there’s no record of me purchasing it.

Comment: Did you get it on line or in store?  If in store, explain to them  the missing piece.  They might let you swap it out for a new one. You'll be hard put  to install this correctly without that piece.

Comment: In store. Customer service said the lot number was dated as being outside of the return/exchange time frame. 

She conceded that it could have been sitting there awhile and within the exchange time.  I’m stuck with it.

Comment: Did you beg and offer to buy her coffee?  And tell her you really can't install the unit without that part? The store will just send it back to the manufacturer to be repackaged or junked.

Comment: I really tried. 30 minutes of trying. It looks like I’m stuck with plan b: go to eBay and buy one from someone selling the same fan model.

Comment: @Erin -- tell the manufacturer's support people that you need a knockout panel cover so that you can install the fan in a fashion that complies with NEC 110.12(A).  Barring that, can you get us measurements of the opening, as well as the thickness of the enclosure's sheet metal, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cant find a replacement cover, you will have to make one. Easiest way is to get a 2x4 or a 4x4 metal cover (preferably with a 1/2" knockout in the middle). Bend it into an "L" shape, and then attach it with short self tapping sheet metal screws.

To attach power, you will need a couple of pieces (links below, you can probably find these at your favorite hardware store): 
EMT (existing conduit) to FMC (flexible metal conduit).
A short piece of FMC (hopefully your wire is long enough)
FMC to 1/2" knockout (this will connect to your cover if it has a knockout otherwise you will have to drill a 1/2" hole

Please note that these links may not be the correct size of connector, but represent the type of connector. Please also read  ThreePhaseEel's note below about grounding

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000KKVUUE/ref=crt_ewc_img_dp_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000KKVUUE)

[https://www.amazon.com/Southwire-55082121-Aluminum-Flexible-Conduit/dp/B002LT0M4W/ref=pd_bxgy_img_2/143-0060259-1607946?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B002LT0M4W&pd_rd_r=8913bc2a-d3d9-4207-bd70-24f159c7959c&pd_rd_w=3Sk1R&pd_rd_wg=lkVjo&pf_rd_p=4e3f7fc3-00c8-46a6-a4db-8457e6319578&pf_rd_r=VNNJ09YK37FJZQ9VQCFV&psc=1&refRID=VNNJ09YK37FJZQ9VQCFV](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002LT0M4W)

[https://www.amazon.com/Halex-20421-2-Inch-Squeeze-Connector/dp/B006X15ZWS/ref=pd_lpo_60_t_0/143-0060259-1607946?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B006X15ZWS&pd_rd_r=51ae619f-ed25-4856-a7c9-c5cdaee4fd3e&pd_rd_w=qsDiY&pd_rd_wg=Z6IJb&pf_rd_p=7b36d496-f366-4631-94d3-61b87b52511b&pf_rd_r=DTK6KWNNB17N7TBWBJ4D&psc=1&refRID=DTK6KWNNB17N7TBWBJ4D](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006X15ZWS)

Comment: Note that they'll need to use a *fine pitch* self-tapper (10-32, look for a Garvin/Southwire GSST) when attaching the cover to the box in order to maintain grounding and bonding integrity, or use a *grounding locknut* and bond wire to connect to the fan's grounding wire.  Also, a 1/2" conduit fitting won't fit into a 1/2" diameter hole -- 1/2" nominal KOs are 7/8" actual size